# Find duplicates between two google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a script that will find duplicates in a cell of another spreadsheet and add "Invoiced" into row 'J' of the duplicated, but am struggling to even make a start as I do not understand script too well.

To break it down Spreadsheet1 contains ticket all open orders awaiting invoice across multiple tabs, most of which will change name and more can be added or deleted on a regular basis, two are constant (named "Various" & "Service") and one does not need to be searched ("Rad Search")

Spreadsheet2 Contains all invoiced ticket numbers in column A.

I need to know if Column A Spreadsheet2 appears on any of the tabs on any tabs within Spreadsheet1 excluding "Rad Search" tab, and add a "Invoiced" into Column J.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to start it would be appreciated, as I'm positive I could adapt it to make it work.

Update......

I have been playing around with a code, but I cannot get it to work, as I do not really understand Script, I have copied different elements from different answers across various outlets but it will not work, if I take the filter script out it will place "Invoiced" next to blank cells

This would not be the final code, as I need it to loop through all sheets apart from one, and I can not use id's as there will be sheets deleted, and added as well as modified so I would be continually be updating the script.

```
    function LabelInvoiced() { 
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ").getSheetByName('cm');
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "d/MM/yy");
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18jLxZlge_UFkdTjlO6opuDk1VKeezhEPLe9B7n1OfQs").getSheetByName(formattedDate); 
  var values = s1.getRange(4, 5, s1.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var values1 = values.filter(String);
  var values2 = s2.getRange(3, 1, s2.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
     var resultArray = [];
  for(var n in values1){
    var invoiced = false
    for(var p in values2){
      if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0] && values1[n][1] == values2[p][1]){
        invoiced= true ; break ;
      }
    }
    if(invoiced){ resultArray.push(values1[n])}; 
    for(var i=0; i<resultArray.length; i++) {
  var data = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
   for(var m=0; m<data.length; m++) 
    if(data[m][5] == resultArray) {
   s1.getRange(m+1, 10).setValue("Invoiced");

}//end of  sheets loop.
}// end of function...
}
}
```

Comment: @Cooper Thank for replying, The Sheet name would be today's date, as there is a new tab added each day. 
The column to be searched is a little more complicated, sheets "Various" & "Service" is Column H, for every other tab its G

Comment: I don't think this is a valid question for Stack Overflow. Break everything down into individual pieces/tasks/functions. With each piece, as you come across issues, post your code, the specific objective of that code, and what issue you're having. That would be a valid SO question. Once you have everything working, you can put it all together to accomplish your end goal. I suggest starting with, "How do I loop through the sheets in a spreadsheet?" Then, "how do I exclude a specific spreadsheet?"

Comment: @Diego, trouble is I cant seem to find what I'm looking for anywhere, tried google, stack overflow, youtube.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a script that's already written to do what you want. If that's what you want, go to Upwork and pay someone to write that for you. If you want to figure out how to do it, look at the [Google Apps Script guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and start learning how to use it.

Comment: @Diego, the whole idea is to learn, but when you cant find the information you need, it becomes very hard, I'm not asking for someone to build it for me, I'm asking for help and advice, I have started a code but can not get it to work.

Comment: At that point, you need to step back and go through examples and quickstarts that Google Developers and other websites offer, and really make an effort to look up every function that gets used. The documentation will either be on Apps Scripts API reference, or a site like Mozilla Developer Network (if it is a part of "standard JavaScript"). When you have a better grasp on the language, you can use what you know to design your program and work through the specific tasks. To begin that stage, write (on paper) psuedocode for your function. Start broadly, then repeat with more detail.